# How to responsive bootstrap tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to develop myself just on bootstrap and I wonder that how to create boostrap tab to responsive without plugin and I found a few plugin for tab to responsive but I want to learn how can I make it without plugin?

for example as image (it can be like this)
[image]

```css
.myTab{
  margin:70px;
  width:700px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="myTab">

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
      <h2>Home</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo asperiores, architecto sunt ex dignissimos nihil eaque voluptate, iure iusto porro, rem animi odio, amet consequatur saepe nam accusamus perspiciatis deserunt?</p>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">
      <h2>Profile</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam possimus neque suscipit omnis dolore at consequuntur commodi itaque dignissimos quibusdam consectetur officia earum laborum accusantium, corporis quaerat ullam modi repellendus.</p>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">
      <h2>Messages</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi inventore dignissimos nisi quisquam sit commodi, laboriosam perspiciatis omnis praesentium voluptate illum magni! Quo, odio itaque recusandae quam veniam tempore cupiditate.</p>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">
      <h2>Settings</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit quam illo magni itaque fugit quo aperiam minus officia a, cumque, error, quidem voluptates cupiditate asperiores dolorum necessitatibus commodi culpa dicta.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: media queries http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp and view port http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Comment: I guess this is not impossible with just css I'll give you an example 
https://inventpartners.github.io/bootstrap-responsive-tabs/

Comment: Bootstrap.css  also  have  same media queries inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't give any width allow bootstrap to set it or use media queries in css. Alternatively use bootstrap grid like col-lg-12 or something which fits. you can also use .container class which sets the width to 800px and is responsive too.

Comment: I guess this is not impossible with just css I'll give you an example 
https://inventpartners.github.io/bootstrap-responsive-tabs/

Comment: ok do one thing, add a parent div with class container and add paddding to it 25 px so the content under it will automatically be in width of 700px. give padding to other class not container as it bootsrap class.

Answer (score 0):

What about taking the float left off of the tab items for the size you want to change it

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .nav-tabs>li {
        float: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess this is not impossible with just css I'll give you an example 
https://inventpartners.github.io/bootstrap-responsive-tabs/

Comment: Ahh kk, now I know what your after. You could do that by having a dropdown floating to the right which is hidden, containing the tabs. then use media queries to show and hide until it works right.

Give it a crack.

Answer (score 0):

I created this one here `code` https://jsfiddle.net/zrss7hor/2/ each time you resize your browser the tabs will adapt it

Comment: You should add more details about your solution, not just a plain link. This would improve the answer quality.